# Efficient way to nofity that query returns new or updated results

Tags: php, mysql, postgresql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have a symfony2 web app using postgresql.  My (simplified) app displays products that have 3 features - price, date available till, and weight.  Users can search for products on these 3 parameters and save the query to their profile.  The query easily runs when they click on the link in their profile.

I want to add new functionality to email the user when there is a change to the results of their saved query.  This can happen if a new product is listed and fits their parameters, or if an existing product that matches their query has a change - say either a price change or the date it is available till is changed.

I am thinking that I need to create a new entity in Symfony2 which will contain all of the product attributes along with the query ID since there can be many products for each query.  Next, I will need to create an event that runs each time a product is either added or changed, that way I can send an email to the user and specify what changed.

Perhaps to simplify this, I could add an updatedAt field to the product entity and instead of including all of the product attributes in the new entity, I will only save product ID and will only tell the user product changed.

Is there a better way to do this than creating a new entity that stores the results of each saved query?  I can add code to show what I am doing, but feel I am at a major fork and could use many different possibilities that may not even involve creating new entities.

Comment: If you use an `updatedAt` field, then shouldn’t it be enough to only save the last time a query got a “new” result as well? And when you run each individual query, you include a WHERE condition to only select products with an `updatedAt` timestamp that is greater than that timestamp indicating when the query last returned a new result – if that delivers any products, then there’s something to tell the user about, and if the result is empty, then there’s not … or am I thinking too simple here?

Comment: (Unless you want to not only tell them _that_ something has changed about these products, but also which attribute in particular it was for each product.)

Comment: I do want to tell them what changed.  I think the updatedAt is simple to add, but maybe I should add more of a time dimension to my product table than just this field.  I could create a new product row every time a product changes, query for the 2 most recent rows, and check which attributes changed.  This way it is all in one entity/table and I can find all the changes over time.  Does this sound like the best approach and works for all possible attributes in the product entity?

Comment: _“I could create a new product row every time a product changes”_ – so basically keep a _history_ of product attributes – which might not be a bad idea in general, for other reasons as well (revision for example; or when showing a user their previous orders, you might want to show them what attributes the products had at that particular time, especially for things like the price).

Comment: But I’d still say selecting the products first via their last updated timestamp, by comparing that to the last new result timestamp of the user’s query, is a good way to go – will perform better, than checking two rows for every product for differences initially already. You should think about including an “active” marker in the product table as well, that can only be set for one of the rows for a product at a time – that will make selecting perform better.

Comment: If I was implementing this I'd have a database-level trigger run `on insert or update` that scans a table listing user's registrations of interest for matches. Then I'd have the trigger emit a `NOTIFY` with the affected IDs as payload, which would be `LISTEN`ed to by background script that would send the emails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by adding a little more functionality as suggested by CBroe.  I added an active flag and am now keeping a history of the product entity when important changes are made.  This way it is simple to query the active products and still query the product that was purchased back in time.  I am now beginning to add a scheduled task to run at set intervals instead of sending out notifications right away for performance purposes, but that is a separate issue.
Thanks for the idea of using the active flag and suggestion for keeping a history since that will be used down the road.